# Aurora PostgreSQL Temporary storage issue for index creation

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

We have migrated some of the data to PostgreSQL from MS-SQL Server. And are using R6G.Large aurora PostgreSQL RDS instance. We have transferred the data using DMS to PostgreSQL instance, and table size is around 183 GB and it has around 1.5 billion records.  Now we are trying to create a Primary Key on an Id column, but it is failing with the below error...

> ERROR: could not write to file "base/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp18536.30": No
> space left on device CONTEXT: SQL statement "ALTER TABLE
> public.tbl_actions ADD CONSTRAINT tbl_actions_pkey PRIMARY KEY
> (action_id)" PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 10 at SQL
> statement SQL state: 53100

When looked at the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Managing.html#AuroraPostgreSQL.Managing.TempStorage) we found that index creation will use the temporary storage of the instance, and for r6g.large has 32 GiB. And for this huge table, that storage is not sufficient hence the index creation is failed with above error.

Is there any workaround to solve this without having to upgrade the instance type, may be by changing some values in parameter group or options groups.

Answer (score -1):

To me, this looks like the storage has run out and not the RAM. You can check this using the Monitoring tab under the heading "Free Storage Space" on the RDS instance in AWS Console.

Try this:

To increase storage for a DB instance

1. Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amazon RDS console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/.
2. In the navigation pane, choose Databases.
3. Choose the DB instance that you want to modify.
4. Choose Modify.
5. Enter a new value for Allocated storage. It must be greater than the current value.

More details here:

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIOPS.Storage
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Troubleshooting.html#CHAP_Troubleshooting.Storage